# Getting multiple data from single cell in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I need to take the data ( image URLs ) that stored in a single cell on my database. Then display it in a while loop.

I've tried the get the data with json_decode but unfortunately, I didn't succeed.

My code is something like this:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM portfolio ";
    $select_all_portfolio_thumbnails = mysqli_query( $connection, $query );

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $select_all_portfolio_thumbnails ) ) {
        $portfolio_thumbnails = $row['portfolio_thumbnails'];
?>

<div class="nv-portfolio-item-box nv-portfolio-items-hidden" id="nv-portfolio-item-box--<?php echo ++$i ?>" >
    <div class="nv-portfolio-item-thumbnails">
        <img class="nv-portfolio-item" style="background-image: url( 'assets/img/portfolio/<?php echo $portfolio_thumbnails[$i] ?>' );">
    </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

The data on my cell is something like this: 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg

On this example, I would like to create 3 image tag with the containing the image URLs in order.

Thanks much.
~
Nathan.

Comment: So what you getting exactly ? `echo $row['portfolio_thumbnails']` and check what exactly you are getting? bcz ur increment the value of `$i` but resign `$portfolio_thumbnails` on every loop

Comment: $portfolio_thumbnails is a string '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg'. It needs to be split into an array and then you can loop through each element. But you are trying to index this string as if it were an array.

Comment: Hello @RasaMohamed, I'm getting a string as '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg'. $i is actually irrelevant to the subject it just increases the id's of the parent box allowing me to do some math on js, I forgot to delete that while posting.

Comment: Ah, thank you @RonaldAaronson. And, I believe, I'm going to do that with explode function, right? Such as -> $portfolio_thumbnails_array = explode( ', ' . $portfolio_thumbnails .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here You have split that string to array then you have to loop that in foreach like below

```
$portfolio_thumbnails = '1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg';
$imageArray = explode(',',$portfolio_thumbnails);
foreach ($imageArray as $key => $value) {?>
    <div class="nv-portfolio-item-box nv-portfolio-items-hidden" id="nv-portfolio-item-box--<?php echo ++$i ?>" >
    <div class="nv-portfolio-item-thumbnails">
        <img class="nv-portfolio-item" style="background-image: url( 'assets/img/portfolio/<?php echo $value ?>' );">
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: welcome, if works then dont forget to mark as answer